# Почему приведенные сказуемые относятся к разным типам?

Tags: сказуемые

Сложное составное сказуемое именного типа:
"Да, признаюсь, господа, я, черт возьми, очень хочу быть генералом." *(Гоголь)*

Сложное составное сказуемое смешанного типа:
"А ты хочешь жить барашком!" *(Гончаров)*

Почему приведенные сказуемые относятся к разным типам?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, признаюсь, господа, я, черт возьми, очень хочу быть генералом (Гоголь).

Хочу-модальный глагол+ составное именное быть генералом , поэтому называется "Сложное составное сказуемое именного типа" или осложнённое составное именное.

А ты хочешь жить барашком ?(Гончаров).Здесь как бы слились два сказуемых-составное глагольное "хочешь жить" +  сост. именное "жить барашком", поэтому относится к смешанному типу.

Разница в том, что в первом примере глагол-связка БЫТЬ, а во втором даже не полузнаменательная связка, а полнознаменательный глагол ЖИТЬ, как в сост. глагольном.

Comment: Скажите, а "хочешь быть барашком, хочешь стать барашком и хочешь жить барашком" - это всё разные виды сказуемых? Мне кажется, что они все смешанного типа, если  уж пользоваться этим термином.  А несмешанный тип - это "модальный глагол + фазовый глагол + основной глагол", то есть одни глаголы.

Comment: хочешь быть барашком, хочешь стать барашком-сложное сказуемое именного типа. Хочешь жить барашком-смешанного типа, здесь жить-знаменательный глагол, потому его основная роль-нести лексическое значение в сост. глагольном сказ., а уже вторая роль-быть связкой в именном - ну вот как дуплексив соединяет в себе два значения, так и здесь.

Answer (score 3):

У Розенталя другая классификация: осложненное составное глагольное и осложненное составное именное сказуемое (трехчленное сложное сказуемое).
Различаются по конечному элементу (инфинитив или именная часть): решил начать работать и решил стать студентом.

В приведенных примерах один тип сказуемого: сложное составное именного типа, только связки разные: отвлеченная БЫТЬ и знаменательная ЖИТЬ.